# массивы в C#, как разбить строки по многомерным или разным массивам

Tags: c#, массивы

Добрый день!
Изучаю С#, столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть текстовый файл с именами, фамилиями и прочей информацией разбитый по строкам (каждому человеку отдельная строка) и между значениями символ "," для разделения. Мне надо этот файл разбить по разным массивам, т.е. так, чтобы в массиве 1 была полная информация о первом человеке, в массиве 2 о втором и т.д. пока не кончатся все люди из файла. Значения в файле идут в строгом порядке, всего их 9. Спасибо за помощь.
Код основного файла:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\employees.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Char delimiter = ',';
                String[] substrings = line.Split(delimiter);
                foreach (var substring in substrings)
                Console.WriteLine(substring);
                counter++;
            }
            file.Close();
            Employee.NumberOfEmployees(counter);
            Employee.AverageSalary(25000);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

Файл txt содержит такие данные

Андрей,Иванов,90,180,m,42,78,1,25000

Сергей,Смирнов,120,175,m,33,81,2,27000

Comment: Так а чем вас не устраивает вот этот ваш код?

Comment: тем, что мне надо проводить определенные операции с отдельными числами и выдирать его из такого огромного массива неудобно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте сделал бы `List<T>`, который содержал бы в себе каждого человека.

Зная то, что у нас в файле каждый человек идет с новой строки, а на каждой строке ровно по 9 параметров (и не меняется!) - мы можем сделать следующее:

Создадим класс, который будет в себе содержать 9 параметров (для примера все `string` и одного названия, но лучше создавать сразу нужные типы и правильные названия!).

```
public class Person
{
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
    public string Param3 { get; set; }
    public string Param4 { get; set; }
    public string Param5 { get; set; }
    public string Param6 { get; set; }
    public string Param7 { get; set; }
    public string Param8 { get; set; }
    public string Param9 { get; set; }
}
```

Отлично, теперь загрузим файл построчно в массив:

```
var file = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");
```

Ну а дальше, давайте создадим коллекцию `List<T>`, которая будет содержать в себе объекты с необходимыми значениями:

```
List<Person> list = file.Select(s => s.Split(','))
                .Select(person => new Person
                {
                    Param1 = person[0],
                    Param2 = person[1],
                    Param3 = person[2],
                    Param4 = person[3],
                    Param5 = person[4],
                    Param6 = person[5],
                    Param7 = person[6],
                    Param8 = person[7],
                    Param9 = person[8]
                })
                .ToList();
```

Поясню код выше: Мы из ранее полученной коллекции с нашими строками, берем каждый элемент и с помощью `Split(',')` разбиваем его по символу `,`, из получившихся данных мы опять перебираем каждый элемент, создавая под каждого человека объект `Person` (ранее созданный класс), заполняя его нашими данными из разбитой строки. Ну и все получившееся мы переводим в `List<Person>` коллекцию.

В итоге у нас будет коллекция с которой легко работать в дальнейшем, к примеру:

```
list[0].Param1
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока писал, уже появился ответ. Оставлю это здесь. Ну, не зря же я потратил время!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = @"D:\employees.txt";

        Dictionary<int, string[]> dictionary = GetPeople(file);

        int numberOfEmployees = dictionary.Count;
        double averageSalary = dictionary.Values
                                         .Select(s => Int32.Parse(s[8]))
                                         .Average();

        PrintResults(dictionary, numberOfEmployees, averageSalary);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Dictionary<int, string[]> GetPeople(string file)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string[]> result = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();

        Char delimiter = ',';
        int counter = 0;
        string line = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    result.Add(counter, line.Split(delimiter));
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Возникла ошибка чтения файла: {e.Message}");
        }

        return result;
    }


    private static void PrintResults(Dictionary<int, string[]> dictionary, int number, double average)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("==Работники==");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Всего: {number}");


        foreach (string[] person in dictionary.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Имя: {person[0]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Фамилия: {person[1]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Вес: {person[2]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Рост: {person[3]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Пол: {person[4]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Возраст: {person[5]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Параметр 1: {person[6]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Параметр 2: {person[7]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Зарплата: {person[8]}");

            Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 20));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new String('_', 50));
        Console.WriteLine($"Средняя зарплата: {average}");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо. Где-то в глубине души я так и предполагал.
Листинг файла с классами выглядит так

```
public abstract class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName; // имя работника предприятия
        public string LastName; // фамилия работника предприятия
        public double Weight; // вес работника предприятия
        public double Growth; // рост работника предприятия
        public char Sex; // пол работника предприятия
        public int Age; // возраст работника предприятия
        public int Kpi; // оценка работы сотрудника по 100 бальной шкале
        public int Department; // идентификатор должности: 1 - технический инженер, 2 - менеджер по продажам, 3 - руководитель отдела

        public virtual void Position(int Department)
        {
        }
        public static void NumberOfEmployees(int n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Численность сотрудников на предприятии составляет: {n} человек.");
        }
        public static void AverageSalary(int averagesalary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Средняя заработная плата на предприятии: {averagesalary} рублей.");
        }

        public void BestEmployee(string firstname, string lastname, string position)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Лучший работник: {firstname} {lastname}, {position}.");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если смотреть конкретно на вашу задачу (разбить на массивы), то решение такое:

```
List<string[]> ParseFile(string path)
{
    List<string[]> returned = new List<string[]>();
    string[] AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    foreach(var line in AllLines)
        returned.Add(line.Split(','));

    return returned;
}
```

Всё. На выходе получаешь список, где каждый элемент - это один работник. А элемент - это массив данных о работнике разбитый запятой. С этим списком уже можешь работать, как пожелаешь.